SSIS package not working once deployed on SSMS
I have an SSIS package that transfers a table from Server A to Server B.
The package works fine until I deploy it on to SSMS.
I've tried deploying the package to Server A and I get an error saying it cannot connect to Server B.
I've also tried deploying the package to Server B and running, but I get an error saying it cannot connect to Server A.

Transfer SQL Server Objects Task:Error: The Validate method on the task failed and returned error code 0x80131501(Failed to connect to server A) The validate methos must succeed and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.

Can anyone help please?

You can't deploy SSIS packages to SSMS, it's just an IDE (like) application. Do you mean you've deployed it to SQL Server? What deployment method did you use? HOw are you executing the package?

My guess is you have permissions to access Server A. but the account running the package on Server B does not have those same permissions.

Sounds like permissions issue (or even firewall issues).
